# How to keep number of row in sql results continue in PHP pagination ?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have these PHP code that generate results along with pagination.

For this code, I set it 5 rows for each page. But the problem is the **number** is not continuously increase when I click on the next page.

What I want to achieve is when it hit 1st page, the number will be (1-5), 2nd page (5-10).

Here's my code :

**index.php**

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>address</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count( $results->data ); $i++ ) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $page++; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['address']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>                                                    
    <?php echo $Paginator->createLinks($links); ?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
try {
    $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
$limit = ( isset( $_GET['limit'] ) ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 5;
$page  = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$links = ( isset( $_GET['links'] ) ) ? $_GET['links'] : 7;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC";

require_once 'Paginator.php';
$Paginator  = new Paginator($connect, $query);
$results    = $Paginator->getData($limit, $page);
?>
```

**Paginator.php**

```
<?php
class Paginator {
    private $konek;
    private $batas;
    private $halaman;
    private $habeit;
    private $semua;

    public function __construct($conn, $query) {

        $this->konek = $conn;
        $this->habeit = $query;

        $rs= $this->konek->prepare( $this->habeit );
        $rs->execute();
        $this->semua = $rs->rowCount();

    }

    public function getData( $limit = 10, $page = 1 ) {

        $this->batas    = $limit;
        $this->halaman  = $page;

        if ( $this->batas == 'all' ) {
            $query = $this->habeit;
        } else {
            $query = $this->habeit . " LIMIT " . ( ( $this->halaman - 1 ) * $this->batas ) . ", $this->batas";
        }
        $rs = $this->konek->prepare( $query );
        $rs->execute();
        while ( $row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $results[]  = $row;
        }

        $result         = new stdClass();
        $result->page   = $this->halaman;
        $result->limit  = $this->batas;
        $result->total  = $this->semua;
        $result->data   = $results;

        return $result;
    }

    public function createLinks( $links ) {
        if ( $this->batas == 'all' ) {
            return '';
        }
        $last       = ceil( $this->semua / $this->batas );

        $start      = ( ( $this->halaman - $links ) > 0 ) ? $this->halaman - $links : 1;
        $end        = ( ( $this->halaman + $links ) < $last ) ? $this->halaman + $links : $last;

        $html       = '<ul class="pagination">';

        $class      = ( $this->halaman == 1 ) ? "disabled" : "";
        $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . ' symbol"><a href="?limit=' . $this->batas . '&page=1">&laquo;</a></li>';
        $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . ' symbol"><a href="?limit=' . $this->batas . '&page=' . ( $this->halaman - 1 ) . '">&lsaquo;</a></li>';

        if ( $start > 1 ) {
            $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->batas . '&page=1">1</a></li>';
            $html   .= '<li><span class="titik">...</span></li>';
        }

        for ( $i = $start ; $i <= $end; $i++ ) {
            $class  = ( $this->halaman == $i ) ? "active" : "";
            $html   .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->batas . '&page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
        }

        if ( $end < $last ) {
            $html   .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
            $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->batas . '&page=' . $last . '">' . $last . '</a></li>';
        }

        $class      = ( $this->halaman == $last ) ? "disabled" : "";
        $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . ' symbol"><a href="?limit=' . $this->batas . '&page=' . ( $this->halaman + 1 ) . '">&rsaquo;</a></li>';
        $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . ' symbol"><a href="?limit=' . $this->batas . '&page=' . ( $last ) . '">&raquo;</a></li>';

        $html       .= '</ul>';

        return $html;
    }

}
```

Appreciate if someone can help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<td><?php echo $page++; ?></td>
```

Use

```
<td><?php echo ($page - 1) * 5 + $i; ?></td>
```

If you are on first page, the `$page` will be 1. For the first loop it will evaluate like:

```
<td><?php echo (1 - 1) * 5 + 1 ?></td>
```

Which prints `1`, so on for the page 2, the output will start from `6`

Comment: It start with the number 0 . how to fix it ?

Comment: Check the value of $page, as per code it can't be 0, unless you are getting 0 value from query string. You can also change ($page - 1) * 5 + $i to ((empty($page) ? 1 : $page) - 1) * 5 + $i. This will use 1 if the value of $page is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your number column. below for loop.

```
$output = ($page - 1) * 5 + $i + 1;
```

and inside

just `echo $output;`

```
<td><?php echo $output; ?></td>
```